# Stylus and touch don't work with Ubuntu 19.04 on Thinkpad L390 Yoga

Tags: 19.04, thinkpad, touchscreen, stylus

I have bought a Lenovo Thinkpad L390 Yoga, which comes with a stylus and touchscreen, and then installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 in dual boot mode.

In Windows the touchscreen and stylus work fine, I can write notes in OneNote etc. In Ubuntu however the stylus and the touchscreen are only recognised as the mouse cursor (e.g. I cannot scroll with touch in firefox, it just selects text as if you are holding down the left mouse button, in note apps there is just a text cursor on the stylus' position).

In the Ubuntu Wacom Settings the stylus is not recognized either.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 056a:5159 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2a70:9011  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

xsetwacom --list:

```
Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus  id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser  id: 16  type: ERASER
```

Do I need to install something else?
Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux applications do not treat touchscreens any differently from a mouse. I find that Firefox will select text with a single finger, but Chrome will smooth-scroll with a single finger. Most file browsers select with a single finger, but its possible that some may scroll. This is normal and not usually something that can be "fixed" by the user. You can try using different software or asking the software developer to change how they treat touchscreen input.

As for the control panel: if your tablet isn't recognized, then your device is probably missing from the libwacom database. Go to https://github.com/linuxwacom/wacom-hid-descriptors/ and follow the instructions at the bottom of the page to gather and submit information about your hardware. This will allow the developers to update the database. The control panel's support for tablet PC styli is still a work in progress, so it is normal if the stylus itself is not recognized for the time being.